# Hibernate Search Annotations and Lucene Fields

Tags: java, lucene, annotations, indexing, hibernate-search

Is there a library out there that can scan a pojo data model for Hibernate Search Annotations and list the Lucene fields (index directory structure) that will be created by the annotations found in that model?